# Cairo: circular path with thick stroke

Tags: graphics, cairo, pango

With Cairo, stroking a circular path with a thick stroke has an undesired result. The circles have a hollow region. Is there a way to prevent this problem?

[image]

Comment: Which fill rule are you using? Does setting the fill rule are you using? Does changing to the other fill rule make a difference? I'm not quite sure whether this should make a difference, hence only a comment.

Comment: Both fill rules produce the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Work-around:

Use `cairo_copy_path_flat` to flatten the path, and stroke that.

[image]